# Disabling a Spinner completely and preventing it form showing it's items in android when disabled

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am setting a spinner to the diabled state by using `mySpinner.setEnabled(false);`

The spinner is disabled and greyed out, but when you click it on it, it shows the it's items in a menu as if it is not disabled!!!

Does any body what could be the problem? Is it a bug in android ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while `setEnabled(false)` should do the job, disabling all interaction with the spinner can be achieved by also calling both `setClickable(false)` and `setFocusable(false)`

Answer (score 1):

Use mySpinner.setClickabe(false);
and mySpinner.setFocusable(false);

Comment: yes thank you it worked, but had to choose the first answer :)